# How do I use the uri stored in a select option value when I click a button in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have the following `onClick` function with my `select` dropdown and `button`:

```js
function functionLooking() {
  var link = document.getElementById("lookingForThis").value;
  window.alert(link);
  location.href(decodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("lookingForThis").value));
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="lookingForThis">I'm looking for</label>
  <select name="lookingForThis" id="lookingForThis" size="1">
    <option value="/about/our-congregations.php" data-link="/about/our-congregations.php">a multi-cultural church</option>
    <option value="/about/our-programs.php" data-link="/about/our-programs.php">a family-oriented church</option>
    <option value="https://school.faithalaska.com" data-link="https://school.faithalaska.com">a private school</option>
    <option value="/worship/bible-studies/" data-link="/worship/bible-studies/">a bible study group</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" onClick="functionLooking()">Let's Find It</button>
</form>
```

I only have the alert window in the code to see what the value was displaying as. It is not important to my function and is for testing purposes only. My problem is that when I click on the button, the alert window displays the correct string from the value of the selected option. For example, option 1 displays `/about/our-congregations.php`. However, when you click ok on the alert the page just refreshes but appends the url with the select element id and encoded uri like so: `/?lookingForThis=%2Fabout%2Four-congregations.php`.

I'm not very skilled in Javascript as you can see so I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I have tried `encodeURI`, `decodeURI` most recently to no success. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Angeliss44 Make the following change in the `functionLooking` method.

```js
function functionLooking() {
  var link = document.getElementById("lookingForThis").value;
  location.href = link;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="lookingForThis">I'm looking for</label>
  <select name="lookingForThis" id="lookingForThis" size="1">
    <option value="/about/our-congregations.php" data-link="/about/our-congregations.php">a multi-cultural church</option>
    <option value="/about/our-programs.php" data-link="/about/our-programs.php">a family-oriented church</option>
    <option value="https://school.faithalaska.com" data-link="https://school.faithalaska.com">a private school</option>
    <option value="/worship/bible-studies/" data-link="/worship/bible-studies/">a bible study group</option>
  </select>
  <input type='button' value="Let's Find It" onClick="functionLooking()"/>
</form>
```

The problem was the button of type submit was adding all the form properties as query parameters in the url. It should definitely work now.

Comment: this is what I originally had and it was doing the same thing. I just tried it again to confirm and it is still doing it.

Comment: no, it is still appending `/?lookingForThis=%2Fabout%2Four-congregations.php` to the url.

Comment: check for the 404 logs in the browser console they creating correct urls

Comment: I apologize. I didn't see that you changed your answer above to address the type of button. I just changed it from submit to button and now it doesn't append anything after the url but it also doesn't go anywhere. The alert window still pops up but nothing happens after I click ok.

Comment: Your answer works perfectly. It's getting late here and I'm exhausted so I didn't notice that I still had `location.href(link)` instead of `location.href = link`. Thank you so much for the help.